# iOS 8.1 image display

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8.1, ios-autolayout

Having a weird problem and can't find anything after over an hour of searching.

I am using Xcode 8 but also experience the issue when using Xcode 7 (I copied the project directory and tested in Xcode7 - I am working in Xcode 8 and created the project in Xcode 8, I only did this for testing purposes) to run the project in the simulator. I have no code in the view controller at this point so I know the problem is not related to code.

I have a simple view created in a storyboard but when I run it on any 8.1 simulator or device the logo appears stretched/skewed.

[image: screenshot]

The original image is below:

[image]

I have created this simple placeholder image to make the point, originally I was using our company logo - so I know it's not an issue with the image since this one was just created.

I have tried removing all constraints from the image and just using width, height, and position constraints but the issue still persists.

Has anybody seen this happen before? What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: did you try programatically adding a uiimageview?

Comment: Is the problem present on iOS 8.4? The number of iOS 8 users who have not upgraded from iOS 8.1 is probably vanishingly small.

Comment: @matt The issue doesn't occur with 8.4 - according to Apple (https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/) only 11% of users are using 8.x so I'll probably just figure it out later.

Comment: "only 11% of users are using 8.x" And of those, I bet 0% are using 8.1. So the problem you are posing is sort of artificial. There was a bug and they fixed it, so what is the point of re-introducing the bug?

Answer (score 1):

you may change the uiimageview's view mode to "Aspect Fill" or "Aspect Fit" in the utilities area .
[Check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3QJj.png)